# Atualização de DOM via jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery

Estou com dificuldades para atualizar um elemento, através de jQuery. Vou resumir os códigos:

HTML

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    <h1>Ranking</h1>
    <a id="btnPlayerName" href="#" class="ui-btn-right">Player</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="rankingList" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#pagRanking', function() {
    headerData();
})

function headerData() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('mbPlayerID') == null) {
        window.location.href="index.php";
    }
    $("#btnPlayerName").empty();
    lblPN  = '<span class="ui-btn-inner">';
    lblPN += '<span class="ui-btn-class">';
    lblPN += playerName;
    lblPN += '</span>';
    lblPN += '</span>';
    $("#btnPlayerName").append(lblPN);
}
```

Está tudo OK com a session, mas o `append` não funciona.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Troquei o append por html e não acontece nada. Talvez seja algum problema de escopo pois um alert($('#btnPlayerName').html()) retorna o esperado, mas a página não atualiza (verificada através do inspetor de elementos).

Comment: `console.log(lblPN);` Dá o resultado esperado na consola do navegador que estás a utilizar? `btnPlayerName` é ID único ou está repetido algures na página?

Comment: Estava repetido em todas as páginas e era este o problema!!!

Comment: que versão de jQM estas usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que apresentaste na pergunta está perfeitamente válido e funciona como esperado.

[**Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/G3QU9/)

Considerações a ter quando estamos a realizar este tipo de operações em IDs:

## ID é único:

Como estás a realizar operações num elemento a partir do seu `id`, neste caso o `#btnPlayerName`, tens que garantir que o mesmo é único em todo o documento, não só naquilo que estás a visualizar actualmente no ecrã.

De notar que as classes de CSS podem ser repetidas, IDs são utilizados de forma a identificar um único elemento presente em todo o documento, ver [identificadores únicos](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/id_selector) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

#### O teu problema

O jQuery mobile não se estava a "rebentar" devido aos IDs repetidos, mas estava a operar no primeiro elemento com o `id` indicado que ele encontrava no documento, ao invés de estar a realizar a operação que pretendias no elemento que querias.

Isto justifica porque estavas a conseguir ver o `output` do teu código em condições mas parecia não existir alteração no DOM.

---

Não relacionado, mas podes simplificar um pouco o teu código da função `headerData()` reescrevendo o mesmo da seguinte forma:

```
function headerData() {
    
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('mbPlayerID') == null) {
        window.location.href="index.php";
    }

    var $btnInner = $('<span/>', {class:"ui-btn-class"}), // criar span interior
        $btn      = $('<span/>', {class:"ui-btn-inner"}); // criar span exterior

    $btnInner.html(playerName).appendTo($btn);            // juntar tudo
    $("#btnPlayerName").html($btn);                       // aplicar dentro do elemento alvo
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/G3QU9/1/)